# Is it possible to insert an image using TextArea into database and display it on web by using PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, image, textarea

Is it possible to insert an image using TextArea into database and display it on web by using PHP and MySQL?

If it is possible, show me how to do that.

Thanks.

Comment: We're here to help you sort out issues with your existing code. That means that you need to do the research, and make some attempts. If you then get stuck on something specific, show us your attempts, where you're stuck, example data, expected result and what you're currently getting. You can read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you cannot insert an image into a mySQL database but you can do that using [*php readdir function*](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_directory_readdir.asp). First you can upload your files to a specific folder, and then show them using this function. For doing that, you can use the code below :

```
<?php
$dir = "your_intended_path_here";

if (is_dir($dir)){
  if ($dh = opendir($dir)){
    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){
      if ($file != "." and $file != "..") {
        echo "<img src='" . $dir . $file . "'>";
      }
    }
    closedir($dh);
  } 
}
?>
```

You can insert an image into a mysql database. Here is the tutorial :
[https://www.roseindia.net/sql/mysql-example/insert-image.sql.shtml#:~:text=Following%20is%20the%20example%20of,the%20image%20data%20into%20database](https://www.roseindia.net/sql/mysql-example/insert-image.sql.shtml#:%7E:text=Following%20is%20the%20example%20of,the%20image%20data%20into%20database).

Comment: If my answer is what you are looking for, you should click on the check mark to close this question to prevent spamming.